# How to convert promise based?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

My app is originally loading data from local-storage, Now i am trying to use firebase.
Firebase always tend to return a promise. So I am trying to convert the store into firebase return one.

here is the original one

```
export const loadState = () => {
  const state: AppState = getDefaultState();
  VALID_LABS.forEach(labId => {
    state.labs[labId] = getDefaultLabState();
    STORAGE_CONFIG.forEach(storageField => {
      const { statePath, storageKey, defaultValueFn } = storageField;
      const loadedValue = getFromLocalStorage(
        labId,
        storageKey,
        defaultValueFn()
      );
      cachedValues[`${labId}:${storageKey}`] = loadedValue;
      set(state, `labs.${labId}.${statePath}`, loadedValue);
    });
  });
  return state as AppState;
};
```

---

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, loadState(), applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.subscribe(
  throttle(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
  }, 500)
);
```

as you can see i am making process working fine. But the problem arise when i start using firebase.

my loadState become something like this.

```
export const loadState = (): AppState => {
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/users/' + userId)
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val() as AppState;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }
};
```

So I also need to convert the `store` to accept the `promise` returning from the new `loadState`.
I don't know how to convert it since I am also using `applyMiddleWare(thunk)`

```
let saveState: (state: AppState) => void     ;
let loadState: () => AppState;
if(firebase.auth().currentUser){
  loadState = loadStateFirebase;
  saveState = saveStateFirebase;
}else{
  loadState = loadStateLocalStorage;
  saveState = saveStateLocalStorage;
}

// call loadstate then data,pass it in as second para to appstate store
const store = createStore(rootReducer, loadState(), applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.subscribe(
  throttle(() => {
    saveState(store.getState());
  }, 500)
);
```

Can someone help me

Comment: Can someone tell me y i got a Minus

Answer (score 0):

Add generic.

```js
React.FC<P>
```

So:

```js
const EmailTarget: React.FC<{match: {params: {tokenId: string}}/*put correct type, I don't know it*/}> = ( props ) => {
    const [ loginState, setLoginState ] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:1337/verify', {id: props.match.params.tokenId}).then(res => {
          
        })
    }, [])
```